# Flutter - Partial SlideTransition in widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create the animation below, in which there is widget behind the `Container`.

[image]

I tried to use the class `Dismissible` but its animation does not stop at a certain point, it goes to the end and disappears with the item, according to the gif below:

[image]

I inserted the code into the `SlideTransition` class but I'm not sure how to integrate the `onHorizontalDragStart`, `onHorizontalDragUpdate`, `onHorizontalDragEnd` to generate the expected effect with the hidden back widget.

Could you help me solve the problem?

Follow the code below along with your screen:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;
  bool _dragUnderway = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );
    _animation = new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: new Interval(0.0, 1.0, curve: Curves.linear),
    );
    _controller.reverse();
    super.initState();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Center(
        child: new GestureDetector(
          //onHorizontalDragStart: ,
          //onHorizontalDragUpdate:,
          //onHorizontalDragEnd: ,
          child: new SlideTransition(
            position: new Tween<Offset>(
              begin:  Offset.zero,
              end: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
            ).animate(_animation),
            child: new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                border: new Border(
                  top: new BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.black26),
                  bottom: new BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.black26),
                )
              ),
              padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text('foo'),                  
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution, follow the code below and the demonstration:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(duration: 
      const Duration(milliseconds: 246), vsync: this);

    _animation = new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: new Interval(0.0, 1.0, curve: Curves.linear),
    );
  }

  void _move(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    final double delta = details.primaryDelta / 304;
    switch (Directionality.of(context)) {
      case TextDirection.rtl:
        _controller.value += delta;
        break;
      case TextDirection.ltr:
        _controller.value -= delta;
        break;
    }
  }  

  void _handleDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    bool _isFlingGesture = -details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx > 700;

    if (_isFlingGesture) {
      final double flingVelocity = details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx;
      _controller.fling(velocity: flingVelocity.abs() * 0.003333);
    } else if (_controller.value < 0.4) {
      _controller.reverse();
    } else {
      _controller.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Center(
        child: new GestureDetector(
          onHorizontalDragUpdate: _move,
          onHorizontalDragEnd: _handleDragEnd,
          child: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Positioned.fill(            
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black38,
                        border: new Border(
                          top: new BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.black12),
                          bottom: new BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.black12),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: new IconButton(                          
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0, left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                        icon: new Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                        color: new Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      )
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        border: new Border(
                          top: new BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.black12),
                          bottom: new BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.black12),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: new IconButton(                          
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0, left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                        icon: new Icon(Icons.edit),
                        color: new Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      )
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: new Color(0xFFE57373),
                        border: new Border(
                          top: new BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid, color: const Color(0xFFE57373)),
                          bottom: new BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid, color: const Color(0xFFE57373)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: new IconButton(                          
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0, left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                        icon: new Icon(Icons.delete),
                        color: new Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              new SlideTransition(
                position: new Tween<Offset>(
                  begin:  Offset.zero,
                  end: const Offset(-0.6, 0.0), //controls the opening of the slice
                ).animate(_animation),
                child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    border: new Border(
                      top: new BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.black26),
                      bottom: new BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.black26),
                    ),
                    color: new Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                  ),
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
                  child: new Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text('foo'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),                           
            ],
          )
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution. However, if you would want to be more flexible, the 'Offset(-0.6, 0.0)' should be programmatically resolved. A way to do it is to wrap the gesture detector into a LayoutBuilder which comes with a boxConstraints arguments. Knowing the width of the action buttons and of course their number, it becomes easy to compute the necessary offset as following :

    Offset(-1 * (actionWidth * actionButtons.length)/ constraints.maxWidth, 0.0)